# AWK: where is my error?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with `:`-delimited fields. If the 3rd field of a line is greater than 22, that line should be printed to `file44`. The file looks like this:

```
1:2:3:4
1:2:3:411
1:2:33:42
1:2:3:44444
1:2:3:4333333333
1:2:3:41
```

awk command

```
awk -F: '$3 > 22 { print $0 > file44 }' file
```

but give me this error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=file FNR=3) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put double quotes around output file name:

```
awk -F: '$3 > 22 { print $0 > "file44" }' file
```

Comment: Or do tho redirection outside of `awk`.